# Can I ask questions for one language only?

Tags: support

Are challenges for one specific questions okay?

Suppose I want to ask for *shortest code to plant a memory leak in C++* - would that be okay?

Comment: Those are usually very much frowned upon unless there's a very good reason why the challenge only makes sense in one language (e.g. JavaScript-only challenges because they require DOM manipulation within the browser).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Single-language questions are not strictly prohibited, but they are unpopular, and you can expect to get a lot of down-votes.

(Your example question would also likely be closed as "*Unclear what you're asking*" until you provided a good definition of what you mean by *memory leak*).

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't a *memory leak* in a specific language something well-known? Why would I need a definition?

Comment: @sharptooth, because I would hope you're not just after `malloc(1)`, but that leaks memory and is so short it probably can't be beaten.

Comment: Challenge accepted. `malloc(1);` is 10 characters and `new int;` is 8 characters. Both are good anyway.